# my wordpress doesn't save items to customized widget area

Tags: functions, widgets

well I am trying to add some items to customized widget area but somehow I can't add it.

```
 function wp_widget_init(){ 
   register_sidebar(array(
     'name' => 'header-menu',
     'id' =>'HeaderMenu',
     'description'=>'',
     'before_widget'=>'<div id="HeaderMenuBar">',
     'after_widget'=>'</div>'
   ));
  }
 add_action('custom_widget','wp_widget_init');
```

[image]

head-menu widget is created

[image]

I can add items to widget, but if I refresh the site after clicking all these 3 blue save buttons, 
[image]

header-menu is empty again. What is the problem??

Comment: plz could anybody help me?

Comment: usually, the action would be added to `'widgets_init'` - is `'custom_widget'` a special hook in your theme? if so, have you asked the developer of your theme for help?